# Can I rewind a 4-pole motor to be a 2-pole motor with the same design voltage?

Tags: motor, induction-motor, inductance, induction, winding

I had a 4-pole motor whose winding was irreversibly damaged and I had to cut it off.

I was planning on rewinding it exactly as it was (I measured everything before cutting off), but then I stopped to think I could also rewind it as 2-pole motor.

Is that possible to rewind it as a 2-pole motor for the same design voltage? Noting that, previously, every unit of the main winding were already in series and it worked in 127 V, it couldn't be wired to 220V.

And how do I calculate the total amount of turns the new winding must have?

One approach I tried so far, but I don't know if it's correct, is to make each unit of the 2-pole winding to have twice the inductance of each unit of the 4-pole winding (so the total inductance is the same).

And I'm calculating the "inductance" by simply multiplying the number of turns by their span (once the height of the iron core is constant).

Is this correct?

If this is, one of the consequences would be that this would use far less copper than the original 4-pole design.

Comment: @Andyaka no because that was the a similar question posted by myself and nobody answered that one either. I choose to reformulate the question because perhaps beginning it with a winding diagram was unnecessary and could repel some possible answers to the simpler question

Comment: You should have edited your original question rather than posting what is basically the same question. Space for questions on the front page are at a premium but, if you consider your question to be more important than others, then maybe you have a right to do that?

Comment: @Andyaka Would editing give it any additional visibility? It was no longer getting new views, if no one would see the edit it would be useless. Plus, I wanted to reach some of the same people who saw it first and might have skipped it because it was too cumbersome and specific. I made an entire reformulation in a way to make it simpler and more generic. That also makes the answers to it more useful for other users and learners in general, because it won't be so specific to that particular winding scheme I chose.

Comment: Editing it (I think) bumps it to the top of the queue on the home page I believe.